# Как убрать бесконечный вывод

Tags: java

Решил сделать что-то вроде игры «быки и коровы». Пользователю предлагается угадать вариант компьютера. Но в конце цикла у меня почему-то бесконечно выводится строка n быков, n коров. С чем это связано и как это исправить?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class NewClass {
  public static void main (String [] args) {
    ArrayList <String> number = new ArrayList<String> ();
   int i = (int)(Math.random()*10);
    String s = String.valueOf(i);
    number.add(s);
   while(number.size()<4){
      if(!number.contains(s)){
        number.add(s);
      }
     i = (int) (Math.random() * 10);
      s = String.valueOf(i);
   }    
    ArrayList <String> gNum = new ArrayList <String> ();
    boolean isCon = true;
   int bulls = 0;
   int cows = 0;
   do{
        while (gNum.size()<4){
         int guessi = scan.nextInt();
          String guesss = String.valueOf(gi);//запрашиваем число у пользователя и преобразуем его в строку
          if(!gNum.contains(gs)){
           gNum.add(gs);
          }
        }
        for (int g = 0; g <4; g++){
          String tig = gNum.get(g);
           if(number.contains(tig)){
              if(number.indexOf(tig) == g){
                bulls++;
              } else {
                cows++;
              }
            }
        }
        if (bulls == 4){
          System.out.println("You win!");
          isCon = false;
        }
          System.out.println(bulls + " "+ cows);
          bulls = 0;
          cows = 0;
        }

    }while(isCon == true);
    

    
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы не очищаете коллекцию, в которую записывается пользовательский ввод, таким образом, ее размер всегда равен 4, поскольку условия выигрыша не срабатывает, а условие пользовательского ввода зависит от размера коллекции (тоже не срабатывает), вы попадаете в бесконечный цикл.

Кроме того, на мой взгляд использовать списки в данном случае нерационально. Да, у вас есть индексы, но вы все равно не можете избежать итерации по списку (про бессмысленое преобразование цифр в строку и подобные вещи я вообще молчу). Может лучше так:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedHashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class NewClass {

    private static final Scanner SCANNER = new Scanner(System.in);

    private static final int NUMBER = 4;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set<Integer> hiddenNumber = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        while (hiddenNumber.size() < NUMBER) hiddenNumber.add((int) (Math.random() * 10));

        Set<Integer> userNumber = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        int bulls = 0, cows = 0;

        while (true) {

            while (userNumber.size() < NUMBER) userNumber.add(SCANNER.nextInt());

            Iterator<Integer> hiddenNumberIterator = hiddenNumber.iterator();
            Iterator<Integer> userNumberIterator = userNumber.iterator();
            for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER; i++) {
                Integer numb = userNumberIterator.next();
                if (hiddenNumberIterator.next().equals(numb)) bulls++;
                else if (hiddenNumber.contains(numb)) cows++;
            }

            if (bulls == NUMBER) {
                System.out.println("You win!");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Bulls : " + bulls + "; cows : " + cows);

            userNumber.clear();
            bulls = 0;
            cows = 0;

        } 

    }

}
```

Comment: Спасибо, Дмитрий